# Is there a draggable jQuery slideout tab plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I've seen a lot of jQuery plugins that allow for slideout menus.

Example: (Click the contact tab on the left) http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

Does anyone know of a jQuery library that does the same but allows the user to drag the tab out? An example would be in the CNN iOS app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For so specific needs I think you can do it by your self if you're looking for doing that on a mobile webapp... but I think it's not really a *"draggable"* thing...